# Variable initialization error in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, initialization

I have the following method:

```
private static double mailTypeOne(double oz) {
    double total;
    if (oz <= 16) {
        total = 3.50;
    } else if (oz > 16 && oz <= 32) {
        total = 3.95;
    } else if (oz > 32) {
        total = 3.95 + (Math.ceil((oz - 32) / 16) * 1.20);
    }
    return total;
}
```

When compiling my code, I get this compile error:
`the variable 'total' might not have been initialized`

What part of my code is triggering the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if else statement should end with an else statement, this ensures that the variable `total` must be initialized no matter the value of `oz`

Another way is to initialize `total` to 0.0 during declaration. That is, instead of `double total;` do `double total = 0.0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your else if(s) aren't necessarily followed (to the compiler). You need something like

```
private static double mailTypeOne(double oz) {
    double total;
    if (oz <= 16) {
        total = 3.50;
    } else if (oz <= 32) {
        total = 3.95;
    } else {
        total = 3.95 + (Math.ceil((oz-32)/16) * 1.20);
    }
    return total;
}
```

You could also simplify the above like

```
private static double mailTypeOne(double oz) {
    if (oz <= 16) {
        return 3.50;
    } else if (oz <= 32) {
        return 3.95;
    }
    return 3.95 + (Math.ceil((oz-32)/16) * 1.20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring is not the same as initializing.  Just say

```
 double total = 0;
```